# Unable to connect to MySQL running inside a Docker container (configured using docker-maven-plugin)

Tags: mysql, docker, maven

I'm facing issues connecting to the MySQL server running inside a Docker container. Here's a `docker-maven-plugin` configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.34.1</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <images>
            <image>
                <alias>database</alias>
                <name>mysql:8.0</name>
                <run>
                    <log>
                        <prefix>TC</prefix>
                        <date>default</date>
                        <color>cyan</color>
                    </log>
                    <wait>
                        <log>mysqld: ready for connections</log>
                        <time>750000</time>
                    </wait>
                    <env>
                        <MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD>${test.database.password}</MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD>
                        <MYSQL_DATABASE>${test.database.name}</MYSQL_DATABASE>
                        <MYSQL_USER>${test.database.username}</MYSQL_USER>
                        <MYSQL_PASSWORD>${test.database.password}</MYSQL_PASSWORD>
                    </env>
                    <ports>
                        <port>3308:3306</port>
                    </ports>
                </run>
            </image>
        </images>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>docker:start</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>docker:stop</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I see that MySQL started successfully in the logs:

```
04:20:18.583 TC2020-10-12T04:20:18.583211Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
[INFO] DOCKER> Pattern 'mysqld: ready for connections' matched for container 2f7f66ba896c
04:20:18.611 TC2020-10-12T04:20:18.610295Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.21'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
04:20:18.625 TC2020-10-12 04:20:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
04:20:23.415 TCWarning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
[INFO] DOCKER> [mysql:8.0] "database": Waited on log out 'mysqld: ready for connections' 172861 ms
04:20:23.415 TCWarning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
```

[image: docker ps]

Error connecting via JDBC, `maven-failsafe-plugin` fails to connect: I tried connecting with `localhost:3308`, `127.0.0.1:3308`, `0.0.0.0:3308` and `10.0.75.0:3308`. Also, tried Network type, `bridge`, `host` and `container`.

```
04:20:31.697 TCWarning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
04:20:31.697 TCWarning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
.09:50:31.962 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/test_db_name?useSSL=false&trustServerCertificate=false&serverSslCert= - Starting... 
.09:50:33.291 [main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/test_db_name?useSSL=false&trustServerCertificate=false&serverSslCert= - Exception during pool initialization. 
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3308)(type=master) : Could not connect to localhost:3308 : unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4 (socket was closed by server)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:192)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1346)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:634)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:150)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:89)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:354)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:554)
```

Docker Network Config:
[image: Docker Network Config]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is mostly about mysql version.

It will probably work if you try with mysql:5.7

Security requirements are different in later versions.

it can be disabled with

> default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password

but i don't know where to put it in docker-maven-plugin.

Comment: Finally `mysql:5.7` worked. I did not try disabling this `default_authentication_plugin`. Problem was that in container MySQL prints `mysqld: ready for connections` twice in logs. Final print is after `Temporary server stopped`. Any connection attempt before it will result in failure. Better option was to check `MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.` in logs as it gets printed only once.